# Check purchase with google billing at startup

Tags: java, android, google-api

I'm currently using the Google Billing API to check at startup of my android app if the user has bought the premium package.

I'm using the `queryPurchases()` method to parse the purchases. I would like to ask if this is the correct way to check a purchase without using a server. I've read about the 200000 API limit - is there a better way to implement this?

This is the current flutter method that I run at every startup:

```
Future<void> initBillingPlatform() async {
    try {
      await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.initConnection;
      List<PurchasedItem> puchased = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.getAvailablePurchases();
      String result; 
      bool purchased = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < puchased.length; i++) {
        PurchasedItem item = puchased.elementAt(i);
if ((item.productId == "premium_features_developer" || item.productId == "premium_features") &&
            item.purchaseStateAndroid != null &&
            item.purchaseStateAndroid == 1) { 
          purchased = true;
          if (!item.isAcknowledgedAndroid) {
            result = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(item.purchaseToken);
            print(result);
          }
        }
      }


      isPremium = purchased; 

    } on Exception catch (e) {
      //Se arriva in errore il default è premium=false
      print(e);
    }
    FlutterInappPurchase.instance.endConnection;
  }
```

The method getAvailablePurchases() of this flutter package runs the following code:

```
final String type = call.argument("type");
      final JSONArray items = new JSONArray();
      Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(type.equals("subs") ? BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS : BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
      final List<Purchase> purchases = purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();

      try {
        if (purchases != null) {
          for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
            item.put("productId", purchase.getSku());
            item.put("transactionId", purchase.getOrderId());
            item.put("transactionDate", purchase.getPurchaseTime());
            item.put("transactionReceipt", purchase.getOriginalJson());
            item.put("orderId", purchase.getOrderId());
            item.put("purchaseToken", purchase.getPurchaseToken());
            item.put("developerPayloadAndroid", purchase.getDeveloperPayload());
            item.put("signatureAndroid", purchase.getSignature());
            item.put("purchaseStateAndroid", purchase.getPurchaseState());

            if (type.equals(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)) {
              item.put("isAcknowledgedAndroid", purchase.isAcknowledged());
            } else if (type.equals(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)) {
              item.put("autoRenewingAndroid", purchase.isAutoRenewing());
            }
            items.put(item);
          }
          result.success(items.toString());
        }
      } catch (JSONException je) {
        result.error(call.method, je.getMessage(), je.getLocalizedMessage());
      } catch (FlutterException fe) {
        result.error(call.method, fe.getMessage(), fe.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
```

Comment: Might be beneficial to others to see the code you are using